# React native ScrollView effect like youtube's one

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to get an effect like youtube's one in the ScrollView of my react native app.
I don't really know how to search for this, so if anyone knows of a package or a video tutorial that could help me, I would really appreciate it.

[That's a short video showing the effect I've said](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15s_x0b_9XfUi94Nw3bLAuNsneC4l2JBS/view?usp=sharing), but I believe it is present in all Youtube apps.
Basically, it shows you the header when you drag it up from anywhere on the screen.

Comment: read here https://medium.com/@habibridho/implementing-collapsing-toolbar-using-react-native-4a84e1718f11

Comment: https://github.com/nandorojo/react-native-anchors try this